# How can I get Visual Studio 2008 to align my assignment operators?

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio, macros, alignment

I had this in Vim and miss it dearly now that I'm confined to Visual Studio. I'd like to take this:

```
MyType type_obj = new MyType();
MyLongerType longer_type_obj = new LongerType()
```

To this:

```
MyType     type_obj        = new MyType();
LongerType longer_type_obj = new LongerType()
```

I have found some macros for this on the web, but they seem to be for an older version of Visual Studio (< 2008). Here is one from 2000.

Edit:

Further digging in Google turned up this one:
http://www.omegacoder.com/?p=8

It seems to work to align equals signs, but I haven't yet figured out if it can align the local variable names, too.

Still no clue as to whether I could just get it to perform this sort of behavior with a `Ctrl E+D`, although that might not be practical considering how it works. (It aligns going down from the line which currently has focus.)

Comment: Do you have a link to the < 2008 macro, perhaps it could be ported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a code-formatting extension that aligns assignments and declarations.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd

(It's written for VS 2010 so 2008 might not be supported)

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted provides a working example for VS 2008.  From within the Macro Explorer edit a macro module using the IDE.  Once the IDE is opened use **Project**->**Add Existing Item** to import the .vb file.  Once imported you can assign the individual macros to their own keyboard bindings using the Options dialog.

Additionally, have you considered using a VIM plugin to Visual studio?  [ViMemu](http://www.viemu.com/) seems to have good reviews.  [This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141992/any-free-vim-add-in-for-visual-studio) has other options.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the macro called 'LineEmUp' in *tools > options > keyboard*.